# Propose Merge 'post' And 'http-post' Tags On Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

On Stack Overflow, the [post](/questions/tagged/post) and [http-post](/questions/tagged/http-post) tags are used synonymously.  [The 'post' tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/post/info) also describes that it's to be used to categorize HTTP POST questions.

Would someone with sufficient permission (more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag) suggest one of the tags as a synonym of the other, please?

Comment: The other common HTTP methods have similar duplicate tags.

Answer (score 5):

I'd prefer to kill [post](/questions/tagged/post) as too generic a tag; although for web-focused developers, it will probably implicitly mean HTTP POST, it can also correctly refer to message-passing mechanisms.